# combining variables in double nested four loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, associative-array

In the code below my outer four loop is pulling the row of data being returned by a database. The inner loop is determining  column (or key value of a associative array) to include in the results.

I am then trying to combine the row with the key value (attribute) to return the data associated with the row and key (column).

However, I keep getting `[object Object].KeyName`.

Is there anyway that I can combiner `row[i]` with `fields[j].value` (where `fields[j].value` is Address) to get `row[i].Address` ? .

```
            var substring = "<tr><td>" + rows[i].institutionName +"</td>";
            for(j=0; j<fields.length; j++)
            {

                if(fields[j].checked)
                {
                    var checkbox = rows[i] + "." + fields[j].value;
                    substring += "<td>" + checkbox +"</td>";

                }

            }
            str += substring;

        }
        str += "</table>";
```

Comment: What is type definition of 'rows' and 'fields'? How your 'associative array' is realized?

Comment: rows is an associative array created while parsing JSON  var rows = JSON.parse(response); and fields is an array of checked checkboxes and fields[j].value are names of each of the checked checkboxes

Comment: Are you trying to set row[i].Address to fields[j].value, or are you simply trying to create a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
row[i][ fields[j].value ];
```

In javascript, properties of an object can (usually) be accessed in two ways: `obj.prop` or `obj["prop"]` for selecting properties dynamically.  In other words, `row[i].Address` is equivalent to `row[i]["Address"]`

**Note**: Don't forget that javascript variables and properties are case sensitive, and the convention is to use camelCase rather than PascalCase for object properties (again, usually.)  `row[i]["Address"]` will not be the same as `row[i]["address"]`

Comment: Thank you  I was trying everything...never thought of simply dropping the period between the two parts

Comment: Glad I could help!  If my answer was helpful, can you mark my question as accepted, so that the question shows up as answered? http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png